# A short python program

Tags: python, comparison, operators

I am new to learning python and need to write two lines of code to get the result using comparison operators and not if blocks. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Using one of the comparison operators in Python, write a simple two-line program that takes the parameter n as input, which is an integer, and prints False if n is less than 100, and True if n is greater than or equal to 100.

Comment: comparison operators return `True` or `False` so you can just print out the comparison expression, e.g., `print(5 < 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
print(n >= 100)
```

So it will print `True` if `n` is greater than or equal to `100`, and will print `False` if not, which in this case is less than `100`. Easier to read:

```
n = int(input())
if n >= 100:
  print(True)
else:
  print(False)
```

or

```
n = int(input())
print(True if n>=100 else False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As comparison operators return boolean value(True or False), this is explained in the [value-comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) section in the official documentation.

Taking what said before you should just print the comparison that will be `True`, first taking `input` and casting into an `int`:

```
>>> number = int(input("Choose a number: "))
Choose a number: 100
>>> print(number >= 100)
True
```

the represented code will be 2 lines exclusing the input and the output printed:

```
number = int(input("Choose a number: "))
print(number >= 100)
```

This solution might be more readable:

```
number = int(input("Choose a number: "))
print(True if number >= 100 else False)
```